# Can you schedule a pod on a specific node using `kubectl run`?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a command `kubectl run -it my-pod --image=<my-image> /bin/sh` and I'd like the pod to be scheduled on a specific node.

Is that possible and, if so, how?

Comment: Nope, it is not possible

Comment: That's possible. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Get the hostname:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Schedule pod on a specific node:

```
kubectl run mypod --image ubuntu:18.04 --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "my-node.internal" }}}' --command -- sleep 100000000000000
```

or

```
kubectl run mypod --image ubuntu:18.04 --overrides='{"apiVersion": "apps/v1", "spec": {"nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "my-node.internal" }}}' --command -- sleep 100000000000000
```

You may need to change `apiVersion` value, please find one:

```
kubectl api-versions
```